# Error when calling Java Smooks library from Grails

Tags: java, grails

I have a trouble using grails with Smooks library. On standalone java project it works properly, but after I add them to the Grails project then I am getting following errors:

> package org.milyn does not exist import org.milyn.Smooks; package
>   org.milyn.payload does not exist import org.milyn.payload.JavaResult

It seems that there is an issue with `Smooks` dependency. How to fix those errors?

Comment: It's a classpath issue, and it looks like you put your Java files in the wrong directory (with Maven, they go in `src/main/java/my/package/MyClass.java`, and you have duplicate directory names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that you are missing a library (Smooks) identified by `org.milyn`. The (jar) library should be placed in the `lib` directory or you get it via a dependency in `BuildConfig.groovy`.